# streaming binary executable file

Tags: python, hadoop-streaming

In my streaming job, I want to invoke a executable file in mapper. That's something like this

mapper.py

```
print os.popen('./binary').read()
```

The command is

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -rmr $HADOOP_OUTPUT
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  streaming \
    -D mapred.map.tasks=$MAP_NUM  \
    -D mapred.reduce.tasks=$RED_NUM \
    -D mapred.job.map.capacity=500  \
    -D mapred.map.capacity.per.tasktracker=1 \
    -input $HADOOP_INPUT \
    -output $HADOOP_OUTPUT \
    -mapper mapper.py  \
    -file mapper.py binary\
```

But the result is, the binary file is not execute. I don't know why. Can anyone help me

Comment: Did your binary file have execute permissions for the user you are using to launch the command?

Answer (score 0):

Arbitrary file in operating system can't be executable only because its file format allows file to be executable (e.g. it's a native executable or some script with `#/path/to/interpreter` first line).

Your file system (to which you've added your file) must know that the file is eligible to be executed by setting execution permission bits. You can set those bits using [chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) command, e.g.:

```
chmod +x <path-to-file>
```